I want to run bitcoincore-qt in private main net
I want to do mining with python to test my my python code.the mainnet difficulty is high and also the testnet dificulty is high and the regtest does not need pow.does anyone know how i can test my python code and submit the results in bitcoincre-qt? with minimum difficulty in the mainnet? or is there any other way to test my code full functionality ?

Regtest actually does need PoW, albeit at just a marginal difficulty. I suggest you use that.

my regnet works fine,but the mining is not getting done in my side and it is getting done by bitcoincore-qt .am I wrong?
